# Antimatter creation from collision of photons

Tags: visible-light, collision, antimatter

Can you create antimatter by letting photons collide?

Comment: See [Two-photon physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274322/how-does-gamma-gamma-pair-production-really-work and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/182656/is-pair-production-only-with-gamma-photons

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Photon-photon pair production can be represented by the equation $\gamma + \gamma^{'}\rightarrow e^-+e^+$, which basically means that the collision of two photons produces an electron and a positron (the anti-electron).

Comment: In the case, two photons get converted into a pair of particles, would this this be in any case a particle and its antiparticle? Could be produced two neutrons?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I'd suggest you'd read about [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production), especially gamma-gamma pair production - that'll help answer your questions =)